# Are there legal consequences of being banned by a web service?

Tags: criminal-law, internet, england-and-wales

If you get IP banned from a website (like reddit), while youre on your phone, do you face any legal repercussions? Does it show up on your record? Do you get banned from other websites? Do the police find out? Does your ISP provider find out?

Sorry this is a silly question but I’m curious

Comment: Is there a reason you think you would?

Comment: Someone on reddit told me they’re gonna ask to get me banned. Am I going to face legal repercussions for this?

Comment: Ok. Even assuming that Reddit bans work by one person suggesting it and the ban happening (obviously it never occured to you to ask for them to be banned), why do you believe law enforcement would be involved?

Comment: Well IP address is involved so I thought it’d go on my record or something. Am I going to face any legal repercussions for this, will my isp find out? Am I being completely delusional in thinking these things?

Comment: I didn’t ask for them to be banned because I believe in complete freedom of speech and not pointless censorship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An IP ban prevents a user from accessing a website if they are using a certain IP address. This is done by the website- your IP is needed to connect. There is no need to inform your ISP, law enforcement, or your parents.

Even if there was a chance of you being IP banned from Reddit, which there isn't, this would affect nothing besides making you unable to access Reddit.

Comment: Until you installed Tor.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I am aware of how useless IP bans are.

Answer (score 0):

Freedom of speech is protection from **government** making laws that restrict your speech. Reddit, twitter and such are **not government** and **not performing government functions**. They may kick you out of their place for what you say, don't say, or just because your name contains a character that they don't want to display.

But no, being banned from a service for speech does not incur any need to inform others of your ban. It's between you and the service.

On the other hand, IP-Bans are a measure that is usually temporary in nature due to the nature of shifting IPs, and often come together with account-bans, and account-creation-bans on the credentials blocked accounts had.

Example: you get banned as user TESTTHING from TESTTHING@TESTTHING.TEST, then any account using the same e-mail address gets banned and new accounts attempting to use the same mail address are denied or get auto-banned, together with a ban of the new IP. If TESTTHING uses their sockpuppet from a currently banned IP the usual result is, that the sockpuppet and its credentials go blacklisted too.